# Problem in Double Integral by Change of Order

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

> $$\text{Evaluate by changing the order} \int^1_0\int^y_{4y}e^{x^{2}}dx\ dy.$$

I am unable to solve the following question. I have tried using the following approach. First I formed the equation of lines using the limits of the inner integral which gave equations of $2$ lines.

$$ y = x $$

$$ y = x/4 $$

and the limits of the outer integral gave me the total bounded region as below

[image]

From what I understood, I have to calculate the volume of function $e^{x^2}$ within the bounded area.
Since, from the current order, calculating the integral is difficult, I tried to change the order of integral (as given in question) so this is what I did :

First I thought the current integral divides the current region into small $dA$ and first integrating by $dx$ means that we are taking a strip parallel to $X$-axis with length between $y = x$ and $y = x/4$ and then integrated it all the way above from 0 to 1.

Then I tried to change this order and thought of integrating first w.r.t. $dy$ as this will mean I will divide the region into strips parallel to $Y$-axis but the equation will be divided into two with the inner limits of first being $x/4$ to $x$ and second from $x/4$ to $1$. and the outer limit will change to 0 to 1 for first and 1 to 4 for second. I was solving the integral but then I encountered a problem.

[image]

I am unable to integrate the highlighted term any further. Please tell me where I went wrong.

Note: I forgot the $x$ in the first term, it will be $\frac{3xe^{x^2}}{4}$

Comment: Changing the order in this case does not make the integral easier. You still have to integrate $e^{x^2}$.

Comment: Just as a side note. are $4y$ and $y$ lower and upper bounds respectively or the other way round? You will get opposite sign the way you have changed the order. Also the first term in the last line should have $x$ too.

Comment: The one way that changing the order might make the integral easier is that the definite integral you've highlighted can generally be looked up in an integral table, as its proportional to the cumulative probability of a standard normal distribution, and so this is a "solution" given such a table as an assumed resource.

Comment: @MathLover I just noticed the missing $x$. Yes, the $4y$ and $y$ are lower and upper bound respectively. The first picture is the question with the exact limits. I was also thinking that the limit is going in reverse which can change the sign but I've ignored that for now.

Comment: @jwimberley So I have to look it up in an integral table? Can I use the Taylor series in this case for approximation (If there is a series for $e^{x^2}$)?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\Big[ y e^{x^2} \Big]_{y\,:=\,x/4}^{y\,:=\,x} = xe^{x^2} - \frac x4e^{x^2} = \frac3 4 xe^{x^2}.
$$

Comment: Yes, I forgot the $x$ in the first term. But what about the highlighted integral?

Comment: You won't be able to evaluate that one except by numerical methods. The question is whether the double integral can nonetheless be evaluated in closed form. At this point I'm not optimistic about that. How did you encounter this integral?

Comment: This integral was given to me in assignment. I was thinking of approximating $e^{x^2}$ by using the first 3 terms of Taylor series and then integrating the polynomial but the question asked to do by changing the order.